# Replacement for CrystalReportGridViewer

Tags: .net, com, crystal-reports, business-objects

I have a Crystal Enterprise 10 custom ASP.NET application that uses the `CrystalReports.CrystalReportGridViewer` COM object to display the data from the report to users. I am in the process of converting the application to use BOXI R3.1 and it looks like this COM object does not exist in BOXI R3.1 and I cannot find any equivalent .NET component.

Is there a replacement for CrystalReportGridViewer and, if not, what would the best way be to provide equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no replacement or equivalent to the `CrystalReports.CrystalReportGridViewer`.  The only way to achieve this functionality is to use an existing viewer and see if you can get the output you want or to use the SDK to get the data you are interested in and then output it yourself.  The [RowsetController](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/bip/40/ras/en/com/crystaldecisions/sdk/occa/report/application/RowsetController.html) is used to retrieve unformatted data in the report directly and might be useful for this approach.